# Jenkins to pick a random value from available options

Tags: jenkins

I am running a Jenkins job to create data for test-users .

Now, I need it to pick a random value from the list of users when I generate the data. Right now the job runs daily and pumps data to a specific user set as a default. I have a String parameter that takes this value.

Is it possible to make it pick a random value from a list of say 5 users, so that I have multiple users with similar kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use shell script to get random user each time?

```
USERS=("Tom" "Mike" "Lily" "Sam" "Jack")
user=${USERS[$RANDOM%5]}
```

[image]